# How to play sound by Front Mic In sounds?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, realtek

In Windows in Realtek HD menager i need opt "play sounds in front and rear in output devices"
and double click in "Front Mic" (Red) and change source from Mic to "Front Speaker Output" and It cause that I can play Music in Front Mic In Input ( i have broken Headphones Front Input broken.

I want do it at Linux Ubuntu - how its possible?

Comment: We need more information to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to install the pulse loopback device.

Executing this in a shell

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
```

will load the module for the session, and

```
sudo sh -c ' echo "load-module module-loopback" >>  /etc/pulse/default.pa '
```

will save the configuration for future sessions.

[Credit.](https://thelinuxexperiment.com/pulseaudio-monitoring-your-line-in-interface/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control) to configure the input and output to use.

Look at the tab "Output Devices"; You can set the output by changing "Port".

Comment: Not works. Is visible as Input... not Output..

Comment: But the microphone is an input! Please describe details allways *exactly*. It's not clear what you talk about. It makes no sense to say that for the microphone, and I have no idea what you could mean otherwise.

Comment: Maybe you have a headset? That is when headphones are combined with a microphone that is attached to the headphone. There is usually ony one cable to the computer, used for both parts. But the cable has two separate audio jacks as connector to the computer. Because of this, a headset is not different from headphones with a separate microphone. In the configuration, it should also be handled as two separate devices.

Comment: By the way, please describe more details - but you do not need to worry about writing in good english. Maybe I could not understand all, but then I could ask you. Without any details, there is not much I can do - I would be happy to help you sort that out, and I'm curious now!

Answer (score 0):

`hdajackretask` is a tool to reassign the function your jacks for different input, output or disabled - e g, turn your Mic jack into an extra Headphone, or why not make them both line outs and connect them to your surround receiver?

Install [alsa-tools-gui](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alsa-tools-gui&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

Run `hdajackretask` Then To override one of your jacks:

1. Select a codec
2. Click "Advanced override" checkbox
3. Click the "Override" checkbox for the microphone pin then select the new
   desired function(s), (i.e. speaker, line out)
4. Test out the changes with the "Apply now" button
5. Once satisfied, click "Install Boot Override"

[image]